# Laravel API Invalid Response In My All Api

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

All of my API responses come with HTML tags, how can I remove them?

[image: postman response]

Here is my code

```
Route::get('test',function()
{
    return response("hello world");
});
```

I tried checking and disabling all middlewares.

Comment: Please do not write questions and answer Like This Everywhere, Just Write NORMALLY

Answer (score 0):

Use json method to do it:

```
Route::get('test',function() { 
    return response()->json([
       'message' => 'Hello World',
    ]);
});
```

You can learn more about https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#other-response-types

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{
    "message": "Hello World"
} same problem

Comment: On your postman, choose Json instead of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Route` into `routes/api.php` file instead of `routes/web.php`.

And return data as json type：

```php
# In routes/api.php
Route::get('test',function() { 
    return response()->json(['data' => 'Hello World']);
});
```

You can test this by url `/api/test`, Laravel will auto prefix `/api` in all routes of `routes/api.php` as default.

Comment: My Route Already In routes/api.php